# org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I've trying to connect in MYSQL and I have error when try to add in configure next resource : hibernate.cfg.xml. And have next error org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: resource: hibernate.cfg.xml not found

HibernateUtil:

```
package util;

   Imports

   public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;


    static{
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.addResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            configuration.configure();
            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                    configuration.getProperties()).build();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        System.err.println("Error creating Session: " + he);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(he);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://**.**.**.**/land_of_dkl_db</property>
        <property name="connection.username">*****</property>
        <property name="connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
        <!-- Возможно потом нужно будет поставить MySQLInnoDBDialect диалект -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Логирование sql запросов в консоль -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Есть недокументированная возможность none вместо validate, но вроде validate нас устраивает -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
        <!-- Спросить у преподов, что значит Enables autocommit for JDBC pooled connection -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping class="DAO.logic.User" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

ProjectName.iml (I delete many trash, Import maven jetty and other):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="hibernate" name="Hibernate">
      <configuration>
        <datasource-map />
        <naming-strategy-map />
        <deploymentDescriptor name="hibernate.cfg.xml" url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
      </configuration>
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_7" inherit-compiler-output="false">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/test-classes" />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
  </component>
</module>
```

Project Structure :

```
+project 
++src
+++main
++++java
+++++util
++++++HibernateUtil
++hibernate.cfg.xml
++project.iml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting `hibernate.cfg.xml` under `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Yes it is solved my problem. What the magic ? In project.iml I have the next row: <deploymentDescriptor name="hibernate.cfg.xml" url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/hibernate.cfg.xml" />

Comment: I'm not sure how IDEA is handling its internal files, but `hibernate.cfg.xml` needs to be in the project's classpath in order to be visible from code, and by (maven) default everything under `src/main/java` and`src/main/resources` is included in classpath